# to make a simple web server and urllib2.request work

Tags: python, urllib2, webapp2

Here's my codes:

**Server:**

```
import webapp2
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(self.request)
app=webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainHandler)],debug=True)
```

**Request:**

```
import urllib2
url="http://127.0.0.1:8080?content1=take my name"
req=urllib2.Request(url)
print req.has_data()
```

It seems that when I run my server and hit request to send messege, the `req.has_data()` returns false and the server did not receive any messege and thus no change. What should I do to make server receive the value of content1?

Also, if my server runs at port `8080`, do I need to specify its request port to `8080`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the request to the server.

you should use:

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

or

```
req=urllib2.Request(url)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples

---

EDITED
I made it work locally (on port 8123 since 8080 was occupied). The server is fine

I only changed the client as above:

```
import urllib2                                                                                                                                                 

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8123?content1=take%20my%20name"                                                                                                        
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)                                                                                                                                    
print resp.read()
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: myapp                                                                                                                                             
version: 1                                                                                                                                                     
runtime: python27                                                                                                                                              
api_version: 1                                                                                                                                                 
threadsafe: true                                                                                                                                               

handlers:                                                                                                                                                      
- url: /.*                                                                                                                                                     
  script: main.app
```

I started the server with:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --port 8123 stack/
```

Comment: it's still not working. Python raises some AttributeError:strip. Is my server alright here?

Comment: Don't know webapp2. Try to replace in the server: self.response.write(self.request) with self.response.write("Hello"). So you are sure the server is returning a string.

Comment: Yes, the server is working fine. when i tried manually inputing "http://127.0.0.1:8080?content1=take my name" in my browser.. Is it something else maybe a firewall has blocked my visit here?

Comment: Can you cut and paste the error with the stacktrace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Sample\google_app_engine\send_request_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    resp=urllib.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 179, in open
    fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1056, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 225, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: strip   hope it's not too tedious..

Comment: I updated the response. I only changed the client using urllib2.urlopen and works on my machine. If a firewall blocked your connection you shoul get a timeout or some other error. Strip is a string method. It looks like you are not passing a string to urlopen